# Angular2 - Issue with: RouterModule.forRoot

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm following the `Angular2` tutorial: [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/)

All my tutorial journey has been as expected, but when arrived to the following point:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html#!#add-a-dashboard-

It is not working as it should.

It suppose to be working with:

1- on file: "app.module.ts", uncommenting the code: `RouterModule.forRoot...`

2- on file: "app.component.ts", adding the following lines to the template:

```
<a routerLink="/heroes">Heroes</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I know I should provide a minimized code but I think it is not possible for me because I don't know exactly where the problem is. What I can say you is that I have been following the tutorial step by step and working all the time.

Here you have a source you can download until this point:

https://github.com/nightclubso/project_03

Like it is right now it is working. No compilation problems. But if you do the 2 points above then on the browser console you see lot of errors.

The files you have to modify (as the tutorials suggest) are:

`app.module.ts` having finally the following code:

```
import { NgModule }         from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }      from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule }     from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes.component';
import { HeroService }          from './hero.service';


@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'heroes',
        component: HeroesComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
  ],
  providers:    [ HeroService ], 
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and `app.component.ts` having finally the following code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component ({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: `
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <a routerLink="/heroes">Heroes</a>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
})
export class AppComponent {
    title: string = "Tour of Heroes";
}
```

but for some reason it doesn't display anything.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Please share at least screen with errors you got on console.

Comment: What does `It is not working as it should.` mean exactly. What is the expected behavior, what is the actual behavior?

Comment: Try adding `{ path: '',  redirectTo : '/heroes', pathMatch: 'full' }` as first route

Answer (score 0):

You just have configured `routes` in your app. So because of **`configured routes`** and **`router-outlet`**, you get nothing (as an output). So, here you need to provide your routing configuration explicitly as shown below,

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/heroes',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroesComponent
  }
])
```

Comment: I did this but no success. On the compilation console (tsc) there are no errors. But on the browser I get the errors you can see on: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nightclubso/project_03/master/issues/so_01.png. Project doesn't load on the browser. I commited my changes to the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/nightclubso/project_03).

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue too. If you look at the error message, it says you need to provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element. So you can either (recommended option) open up the index.html file and add

```
< base href = "/" >
```

under the head element giving:

```
...
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
...
```

OR

> go to your app.module.ts file, and where you have your "providers:
>   ..." array, add
>
> `{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : "/" }`

giving:

```
...
providers: [ HeroService, {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' } ],
...
```